# How can i go to next screen while using sliding menu

Tags: android, onclick, slidingmenu

I am using [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library project to implement sliding menu and now i am successfully able to implement it. When i click button it open's sliding menu and now  My question is how can i go to any other activity by clicking menu option.

I want when i click on `My Profile` it takes me to that screen, then if i click `Profile Picture` then some other screen etc... etc...

Below is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.5f);
        menu.attachToActivity(MainActivity.this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.activity_menu);

        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slidingMenu);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                menu.showMenu();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/option_popup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/settingMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#262E38"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/settings" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myprofile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/setting"
            android:src="@drawable/myprofile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilepicture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/myprofile"
            android:src="@drawable/profilepicture" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/changewallpaper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profilepicture"
            android:src="@drawable/changewallpaper" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/notification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/changewallpaper"
            android:src="@drawable/notofication" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/notification"
            android:src="@drawable/commentstrip" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/comment"
            android:src="@drawable/post" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/post"
            android:src="@drawable/chat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/likedislike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chat"
            android:src="@drawable/likeanddislike" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/privacypolicy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/likedislike"
            android:src="@drawable/privacypolicy" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/termscondition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/privacypolicy"
            android:src="@drawable/termscondition" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contactus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/termscondition"
            android:src="@drawable/contactus" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/contactus"
            android:src="@drawable/logout" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you post R.layout.activity_menu ?

Comment: try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) way

Answer (score 1):

Hmm something like this, just a quick pseudo code, you can do the rest.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      switch(item.getItemId()){
       case R.id.profile:
        profile();
        break;
       case R.id.logout:
        logout();
        break;
     }
 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: It is giving error on `switch(item.getID())` and the error is, `The method getID() is undefined for the type MenuItem`

Comment: this is a pseudo code not the exact code :) its not getID() its getItemId()

Comment: what error it says ? it should work.. the other version is that you have list that populates your sliding menu items and set onItemClick but I dont see you doing that, so there is something else... do you return true in this method ? let me edit the code... and try it that way..

Comment: First of all let me clear one thing that i am not implementing menu app, i am trying to implement sliding menu and that i did, now just problem is when click on sliding menu screen i want to open new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
 View op1 = findViewById(R.id.op1);
 op1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
 {
  startActivity(this, YourActivity.class);
 }}
 );
```

Comment: i didn't get you properly, can explain this in brief please.

Comment: I mean you want to perform event on menu item click. am I right?

Comment: Yes exactly, when i click any option i just want to move to next screen that's it.

Comment: if you click on comment in sliding menu it will open comment page

Comment: But what is `op1` in this case and what operation i need to perform inside click event.

Comment: id of your view i have given an example id. you have to give your view id

Answer (score 0):

```
private void displayView(int position) 
{
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new MyProfile();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ProfilePicture();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
```

[Refer this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Use switch case.. using position once you click an item it will take you to that particular class.

Comment: oops.. it is easy if you use fragment IMHO .. just use switch case for how many ever class you want to,!!

Answer (score 0):

You should also override the onOptionsItemSelected method, from the Activity Class.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.myProfile:
        showMyProfile();
        return true;
    case R.id.profilePicture:
        profilePicture();
        return true;
    case R.id.changeWallpaper:
        changeWallpaper();
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Then you can create the corresponding methods where you will initialize your intents

```
public void profilePicture() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ProfilePicture.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It is not working. When click on option nothing happens

Comment: can you post your menu xml? because I think you are not referring to the right xml.

Comment: I don't have anything in menu.xml, i am implementing sliding menu, and that xml i already have listed in above code.

Comment: Have you created the classes for your intents? if yes, do these activities do something?

Comment: Yes i have created classes, but when i implement your code it is not taking me to the new screen.